# Does the word "plethora " necessarily have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning

"Plethora" is frequently used to express an abundance of something in a positive sense.

My understanding of the word is an overabundance or "too-muchness"

Is it a case that the word has changed meaning as it has come into common usage or that it is simply being mis-used?

Comment: It is neither positive nor negative in connotation.  It simply means "a whole bunch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have often  seen the term used with a negative connotation. According to OLD [plethora](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plethora) is a synonym of *excess* and means:

> - an amount that is greater than is needed or can be used.

Also its etymology suggests a negative connotation:,

[Plethora](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plethora):

> - ***1540s, a medical word for "excess of body fluid,***" from Late Latin plethora, from Greek plethore "fullness," from plethein "be full" (see pleio-). ***Figurative meaning "too-muchness, overfullness in any respect" is first recorded 1700.***

(Etimonlyne)

According to the Grammarist, however, the term does not necessarily imply a negative connotation:

[Plethora](http://grammarist.com/usage/plethora/):

> - is an overabundance. The excess here is key; in traditional usage of the word, a plethora is too much of something. ***Today, however, the word is often used as a synonym of plenty or many, which imply abundance but not necessarily overabundance.***

Examples

> - But decision science has shown that people faced with a plethora of choices are apt to make no decision at all. [Daily Beast]
> - The plethora of mixed motives for the west’s engagement with the Arab world make doing the right thing harder in the Middle East and North Africa. [The Guardian]
> - I spent a few hours Monday on the ministry’s website, and was nearly driven mad by the plethora of acronyms. [Globe and Mail]

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plethora) gives as an example *<a biology textbook that is helpfully illustrated with a plethora of excellent illustrations>*.  There's no way that that could be interpreted as a negative connotation.

Comment: @HotLicks - I was finishing my answer, see my edit.Thanks  for your quick downvote. :)